# Timer is not aligned as Center in Dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I am displaying the dialog with Timer and Ok,Cancel options. but Timer is not getting aligned as center, Timer is displaying in the left corner.

**DatetimecustomActivity.java**

```
package com.example.datetimecustom;

import java.util.Calendar;

import DateTimePicker.DateTimePicker.DateWatcher;
import DateTimePicker.DateTimePicker;

import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.util.Log; 
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout; 

public class DatetimecustomActivity extends Activity implements DateWatcher{
    EditText edit_text;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_datetimecustom);
        edit_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1); 
    }

    public void button_click(View view){  
        // Create the dialog
        final Dialog mDateTimeDialog = new Dialog(this);
        // Inflate the root layout
        final LinearLayout mDateTimeDialogView = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.date_time_dialog, null);
        // Grab widget instance 
        final DateTimePicker mDateTimePicker = (DateTimePicker) mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.DateTimePicker);
        mDateTimePicker.setDateChangedListener(this); 

        // Update demo TextViews when the "OK" button is clicked 
        ((Button) mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.SetDateTime)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDateTimePicker.clearFocus();
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                String result_string =  String.valueOf(mDateTimePicker.getHour()) + ":" + String.valueOf(mDateTimePicker.getMinute());
//              if(mDateTimePicker.getHour() > 12) result_string = result_string + "PM";
//              else result_string = result_string + "AM";
                edit_text.setText(result_string);
                mDateTimeDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        // Cancel the dialog when the "Cancel" button is clicked
        ((Button) mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.CancelDialog)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mDateTimeDialog.cancel();
            }
        });



        // Setup TimePicker
        // No title on the dialog window
        mDateTimeDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // Set the dialog content view
        mDateTimeDialog.setContentView(mDateTimeDialogView);

         WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            lp.copyFrom(mDateTimeDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
            lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            mDateTimeDialog.show();
         mDateTimeDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

        // Display the dialog
        mDateTimeDialog.show();             
    }
    public void onDateChanged(Calendar c) { // goi khi co thay doi tu calendar
        Log.e("",
                "" + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + " " + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                        + " " + c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    }
}
```

**`date_time_dialog.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/DateTimeDialog" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
    <DateTimePicker.DateTimePicker
        android:id="@+id/DateTimePicker" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"

        android:layout_height="0dp"

         /> 
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ControlButtons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dip">         

        <Button android:id="@+id/CancelDialog" android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="@android:string/cancel" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/SetDateTime" android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:text="@android:string/ok" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  /> 
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**`datetimepicker.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout 

   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:padding="5dip" android:id="@+id/DateTimePicker"
    android:gravity="center"
     android:orientation="horizontal"> 



    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/hour_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/hour_plus"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="28dp"            
                android:background="@drawable/image_button_up" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/hour_display"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/picker_middle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
                android:singleLine="true" >
            </EditText>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/hour_minus"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="28dp"        
                android:background="@drawable/image_button_down"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/min_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/min_plus"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="28dp"        
                android:background="@drawable/image_button_up" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/min_display"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/picker_middle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
                android:singleLine="true" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/min_minus"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="28dp"        
                android:background="@drawable/image_button_down"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**This my Actual output :**

[image]

Comment: Is the output on Emulator or in Mobile phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this way

Update your **date_time_dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/DateTimeDialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <DateTimePicker.DateTimePicker
            android:id="@+id/DateTimePicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ControlButtons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/CancelDialog"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@android:string/cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/SetDateTime"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@android:string/ok" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Great! thanks for your answer. Can u explain me why it is working when DateTimePicker is wrapped by the Linear Layout.

Answer (score 0):

Please change in following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/DateTimeDialog" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <DateTimePicker.DateTimePicker
            android:id="@+id/DateTimePicker" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="0dp"

             /> 
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ControlButtons"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dip">         

            <Button android:id="@+id/CancelDialog" android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:text="@android:string/cancel" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/SetDateTime" android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:text="@android:string/ok" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"  /> 
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @sarvanan Accept the answer if the answer valid for you